# Footer in not shown in iPhone 13 and other devices, Safari

Tags: iphone, web, safari

Its not shown my footer in iPhone in safari browser... here some content is auth-content is my upper content class and auth-footer is my footer body position is relative

```
 <div className="auth-content">{children}</div>
    <div className="auth-footer">
      <div
        className="text-white"
        style={{position: 'relative', width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
      >
        <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end h-100">
          <Footer linkColor={'#fff'} origin={'auth'} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

here calls footer and in bottom is CSS

```css
.auth-content {
  height: 96vh;
}

.auth-footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 4vh;
  background: #4c6281;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-height: 768px) {
  .auth-content {
    height: 96vh !important;
  }

  .auth-footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 4vh !important;
    background: #4c6281;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```